# How to use file.read() in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am trying to use file.read() in Arduino. I have a txt file with 100 rows and 2 columns. I want to access the data (19,1). How can this data be accessed? I'm using an ESP32 whit the Arduino program. This is the code:

````
#include "SPIFFS.h"

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
 
 if(!SPIFFS.begin(true)){
   Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
   return;
 }
 
 File file = SPIFFS.open("/Wavemono2.txt");
 if(!file){
   Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
   return;
 }
 
 Serial.println("File Content:");
 while(file.available()){
   Serial.write(file.read());
 }
 file.close();
}

void loop() {
}
```
````

Comment: Is there a problem with the above code? Does file.read not work?  Or do you want to use file.seek() to go to a specific point in the file?

Comment: Can you tell us where the fail is??  You have error messages all over the place.  Which one do you see?

Comment: The code is ok. There isn't any error. I need to go to a specific point in the file. For example, the point (19.2) in the txt file. I don't know do it

Comment: If you know what the byte offset is then you can use file.seek() to move the read pointer. You’ll need to read the doc on the use of seek() - you can move forward, backwards, start of file, end of file etc.

Answer (score 2):

The tools you have available to you don't really know from rows and columns.

Assuming the file isn't strictly formatted to the point that you know how many characters in the data you are looking for is, I suggest reading one character at a time in a loop, counting new line characters until you're on the right line.

Then, read the next line, saving to a buffer until you have the whole line, and use string manipulation to pull out the data you need.